# ¿Por qué no me encuentra la imagen con background-image?

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    body{
    background-image: url("views/images/2.jpg") no-repeat center center;

  }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece ser un problema de rutas. al parecer su archivo php se encuentra en `views` , no es necesario volver a acceder intentar con `background-image: url('images/2.jpg');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código:

```
background-image: url("views/images/2.jpg") no-repeat center center;
```

Hay un problema de sintaxis al usar `background-image`:

Según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-image), la sintaxis es así:

```
background-image: url | none | inherit
```

**Donde:**

`url` : Localización de la imagen que se utilizará de fondo.

`none` : Utilizado para especificar que un elemento no debe tener ninguna imagen de fondo.

Lo que significa que `background-image`no admite los atributos `no-repeat center center;`

Si quieres aplicar varias reglas CSS diferentes puedes usar sólo `background` que permite hacer eso, según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background):

> La propiedad `background` **es un atajo** para definir los valores
>   individuales del fondo en una única regla CSS. **Se puede usar
>   background para definir los valores de una o de todas las propiedades
>   siguientes: `background-attachment`, `color`, `image`, `position`, `repeat`**.

Es decir, que admite al mismo tiempo los valores:
`background-color`, `background-image`, `background-repeat`, 
`background-attachment` y `background-position`

**Ejemplo con sólo `background`:**

```css
body {
  background:
    url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/grey-linen-texture-background_1053-253.jpg") no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<h2>Image Background</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

---

**Ejemplo `background-image` usado sin atributos:**

```css
body {
  background-image:
    url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/grey-linen-texture-background_1053-253.jpg");
}
```

```html
<h2>Image Background</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

---

**Ejemplo con `background-image` y atributos (incorrecto):**

```css
body {
  background-image:
    url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/grey-linen-texture-background_1053-253.jpg") no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<h2>Image Background</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: @DarkFenix ¿Y los code snippet, cómo los pongo en comentario? Hay 3 code snippet.

Comment: gracias, el que funciono fue este     background: url("views/images/2.jpg") no-repeat center center;

Comment: @Gamez Estaba investigando si hay casos en los que `background-image` no funciona, para agregarlo a la respuesta, pero no veo encuentro nada por ahora. ¿Qué navegador estás usando?

Comment: uso firexfox...

Comment: @Gamez Ya encontré más datos. He editado la respuesta.

Comment: el que tu aplicas con la imagen alojada me la muestra pero con este no :   background-image:  url('views/images/2.jpg');

Comment: @Gamez O sea, con comillas simples no funciona, pero ¿con comillas dobles funciona?

Comment: ya vi un detalle y es que estoy en images por lo tanto tengo que subir 2 direcctorios ; asi ../../

Comment: si funciona el detalle era que estoy en la carpeta tables y tenia que subir 2 directorios para luego encontrar  la carpeta images para poder seleccionar la imagen, gracias por tu ayuda amigo

Comment: De nada. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.

Comment: gracias a tu ayuda tambien